# Java implementing sound clips, NullPointerException

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to create a class which plays sounds when I call them in a method. However, I get a null pointer Exception every time i try to play a sound. I cannot figure out what object I have referenced but not linked, everything looks good to me!

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Sound extends JApplet// Holds one audio file
{
    private AudioClip song; // Sound player
    private URL songPath; //audio path

    public Sound(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),filename); // Get the Sound URL
            song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} // Satisfy the catch
    }
    public void playSound()
    {
        song.loop(); // Play
    }
    public void stopSound()
    {
        song.stop(); // Stop
    }
    public void playSoundOnce()
    {
        song.play(); // Play only once
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sound s = new Sound("gameover.wav");

        s.playSoundOnce();

    }
}
```

Comment: Always provide a full stack trace when dealing with an unexplained exception. It will help us diagnose the problem faster.

Comment: Also `catch(Exception e){} // Satisfy the catch` is a very bad practice. If it cannot happen - explain why. If it can happen - by ignoring it you get into unstable state. My guess is this exception happened, and now `song` is `null`, and you try to access it in `playSoundOnce()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my own code. I am new to java and programming as a whole. I was trying to learn how to use sound by implementing this code but it never worked.  With that said I did not know that this was bad practice. I will update the code. Thanks for pointing this out!!

Comment: Without a stacktrace, there's no way to know exactly where the problem is. A NPE might be thrown when 1) getCodeBase() returns null, and you call newURL, 2) songPath is null, and you call newAudioClip on it, 3) Sound s is null, and you call playSoundOnce(), among other potential issues.

Comment: Is there a way to check individual elements to see if they are not null?

Comment: @Krzysztof Yes, there is - some of them (by order of better practice first) - (1) creating unit-tests to check them out (For example, a test that creates an object and verify the internal fields are not null), (2) by using a debugger and checking the value of a field (3) By adding print statements on the variable you are interested in

Comment: @amit I used debugger and found out that my variable song = null. My filename constructor is working. I do not understand why song would be null if I assign it a value. Sorry for all the questions but I am learning a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Sound extends JApplet// Holds one audio file
{
    private AudioClip song; // Sound player
    private URL songPath; //audio path

    public Sound(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),filename); [1]
            song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} // Satisfy the catch
    }
    public void playSound()
    {
        song.loop(); [2]
    }
    public void stopSound()
    {
        song.stop(); [2]
    }
    public void playSoundOnce()
    {
        song.play(); [2]
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sound s = new Sound("gameover.wav");

        s.playSoundOnce();

    }
}
```

Possible places where your null pointer can be

1. if getCodeBase() throws a NPE
2. if for some reason song was not initialized (an exception was thrown in #1) so you're trying to call a method on a null object

I bet you're getting a problem at #1, then your song object is not being created and then you're getting a NPE everytime you try to play it because of #2.

Most probably, songPath is invalid or not reachable by your applet, maybe because the path is wrong or because your applet needs permissions [to access the file outside its sandbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)